# How to fill in with color the area of a function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have an ellipse created with the following code:

```
angles = atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
t = linspace(0, 2 * pi, 300); % Absolute angle parameter
X = a_ellipse * cos(t);
Y = b_ellipse * sin(t);
x_ellipse = (x1 + x2) / 2 + X * cos(angles) - Y * sin(angles);
y_ellipse = (y1 + y2) / 2 + X * sin(angles) + Y * cos(angles);
plot(x_ellipse,y_ellipse,'-r','LineWidth',2)
axis equal
```

Where (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are the "points" of the ellipse. I want to fill in this ellipse with color.

I have tried `area(x_ellipse,y_ellipse)` but it gives me this result:

[image: attempt to fill in the ellipse]

I only want the inside of the ellipse to be red too.

[image: ellipse with only the border]

Comment: [patch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) should do the trick (Note that you might have to repeat the first point at the end of your vectors to have a closed polygon)

Comment: Also, your example is not reproducible, as we don't have values for `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2`